# Diseño web en HTML y CSS, diseño de HEADER

Tags: html, css, web, diseño

Yo ya tengo todo diseñado, todo bien modificado, pero este problema me surgió cuando revise mi pagina.
Ya revise muchas veces el cogido HTML y CSS, pero no miro ningún error.
por eso he venido aquí para que me ayuden con estas preguntas.
¿Por qué el diseño de mi icono y el texto aparece delante del heder?
¿Cómo puedo poder mi icono y el texto a tras del heder?

```css
.button {
    display: flex;
    position:relative;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin: 19px 23px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.button:hover .icon{
    background: #ffa500;
    color:white;
}
.icon:before {
    position:relative;
    bottom: -13px;
    margin-left: 16px;
}
.icon {
    margin-right: 350px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #ffa500;
    color: #ffa500;
}
.description {
    position:absolute;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 120px;
    color: rgb(150, 148, 148);
}
.titulo {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: "Merri";
    color: rgb(66, 65, 62, .9);
    font-weight: 600;
}
.parraf{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Arimo";
}
icon-plane:before {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon icon-hotel">
   <img url="CSS/fontello.css">
   </div>
   <div class="description">
   <h9 class="titulo">Alojamiento</h9>
   <p class="parraf">Disponemos de instalaciones comodas y de diferente clase.</p>
   </</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola usa en atributo **z-index** para controlar los *niveles de profundidad* de las capas lo que tenga z-index mayor se muestra encima.

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero ya le agregue y no lo posiciona atras. No cambia nada

Comment: No está relacionado con la pregunta, pero esta línea '<img url="CSS/fontello.css">' creo que está mal por dos razones, una, el atributo es src no url, dos, el tag img espera una imagen, no un css. Por otro lado, la línea '</</div>' también está mal, debería ser '</div>'. El html aguanta de todo, pero no por eso se debe escribir mal ya que dificulta encontrar errores a posterior.

Answer (score 0):

Aplica una regla de estilo `z-index: 999999` a la cabecera, si tiene posición fija (que es lo que parece con la captura que has incluido) debería funcionarte.

El valor del `z-index` puedes ajustarlo mejor, con un número grande te aseguras que siempre esté por encima de cualquier contenido (incluso modales, si los hubiera).

Comment: gracias amigo, se soluciono :))